# How to sort an arraylist of objects?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have a class

```
public class SMS 
{
    public String addr;
    public String body;
    public String type;
    public String timestamp;
}
```

Now I have made an arrayList of objects

```
ArrayList<SMS> temp = new ArrayList<SMS>();
```

I have added the values. Now I want to sort the arrayList with respect to the timestamp.

How do I sort the arrayList in ascending/descending order with respect to the timestamp?

Comment: What is the format of `timestamp`?

Comment: Its a string e.g timestamp="1033123131";

Comment: Is there a reason why you are storing it as String? Wouldn't `long` type be better?

Comment: I would convert it to long that is not the problem. The problem is how do I sort it then?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sort ArrayList of custom Objects by property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compare Strings containing timestamps you need to first parse them to long `Long.parseLong(timestamp)` and then compare numeric value using `Long.compare(x,y)`.

So try maybe with `Collections.sort(yorList, yourOwnComparator)` like

```
Collections.sort(temp, new Comparator<SMS>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(SMS o1, SMS o2) {
        return Long.compare(Long.parseLong(o1.timestamp), 
                            Long.parseLong(o2.timestamp));
    }
});
```

---

If you can change type of timestamp to `long` this code could look like

```
Collections.sort(temp, new Comparator<SMS>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(SMS o1, SMS o2) {
        return Long.compare(o1.timestamp, o2.timestamp);
    }
});
```

In Java8 you can even use lambdas to shorten code even more

```
Collections.sort(temp, (SMS o1, SMS o2) -> Long.compare(o1.timestamp, o2.timestamp));
```

or even

```
Collections.sort(temp, (o1,  o2) -> Long.compare(o1.timestamp, o2.timestamp));
```

Comment: That's a good alternative, with some protection against o1 and/or o2 being null.

Comment: @Snicolas True. To avoid NPE OP would have to make sure that `timestamp` is not `null`. But I think that letting `timestamp` be `null` may be bigger issue so throwing NPE in this case would be informing that somewhere (earlier) in code exists a way/bug which lets timestamp be `null`s. Decision where to handle it belongs to OP.

Answer (score 8):

```
Collections.sort(temp);
```

will sort a collection of [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) objects, so class  `SMS` has to implement `Comparable<SMS>` :

```
public class SMS implementes Comparable<SMS>
{
    public String addr;
    public String body;
    public String type;
    public String timestamp;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SMS other) {
       //for instance
       return addr.compareTo( other.addr );
    }
}
```

It is usually a good practice, when implementing [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) to also implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` so that equality between objects is consistent with their comparison. Also, you should add some protection against null values :

```
public class SMS implements Comparable<SMS>
{
    public String addr;
    public String body;
    public String type;
    public String timestamp;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(SMS other) {
       //for instance
       if( addr == null ) {
           return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
       }
       return addr.compareTo( other.addr );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
       //for instance
       if( other instanceof SMS ) {
          if( addr == null && ((SMS) other) != null ) {
              return false;
          }
          return addr.equals(((SMS) other).addr);
       } else {
          return false;
       }
       return addr.compareTo( other.addr );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashcode() {
       //for instance
       if( addr == null ) {
           return 0;
       }
       return addr.hashcode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that the correct answer ? A few more upvotes would get me enlightened : http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/19/enlightened

Answer (score 0):

Use `Comparable` (see [example here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/)), 
it should be something like this:

```
public class SMS implements Comparable<SMS>{

    ....

    public int compareTo(SMS compareSms) { 
        return this.timestamp.compareTo(compareSms.timestamp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the general testing code:

```
ArrayList<SMS> temp = new ArrayList<SMS>();

// testing values
SMS a = new SMS();
a.setTime("a time");
SMS b = new SMS();
b.setTime("b time");
SMS c = new SMS();
c.setTime("c time");
temp.add(a);
temp.add(b);
temp.add(c);

// descending sort
Collections.sort(temp, new Comparator<SMS>() {
    public int compare(SMS text1, SMS text2) {
        // compare timestamps from the SMSs
        return text2.getTime().compareTo(text1.getTime());
    }
});

// print it out to test
for (SMS sms : temp) {
    System.out.println(sms.getTime());
}
```

If I want to change it from ascending to descending, I would simply need to switch the way I compare the text messages. Look at this:

```
return text2.getTime().compareTo(text1.getTime()); // descending
return text1.getTime().compareTo(text2.getTime()); // ascending
```

---

Note: I assume that `getTime()` returns the timestamp of the text message, and you need to add this import statement to your class: `import java.util.Collections;` or just `import java.util.*;`

To use the `getTime()` and `setTime(String timestamp)` methods, your class may look like this:

```
public class SMS 
{
    public String addr;
    public String body;
    public String type;
    public String timestamp;

    public void setTime(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return timestamp;
    }
}
```